# `GLIBC_2.7' not found error in Android emulator while launching the AVD File

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, redhat

I am using Red Hat 5 and android-sdk_r11-linux_x86.tgz sdk. I am getting `GLIBC_2.7' not found error when i try to start a virtual device from Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Any help on this would be really useful.

-Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [sdk requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) you will see that glibc >= 2.7 are required.

AFAIK rhel 5 (5.6) uses glibc 2.5

You could compile yourself the glibc >= 2.7 into a separated directory for instance /usr/local/glibc-new and than launch the AVD manager exporting the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/glibc-new`

This should work

Comment: Thanks a lot Francesco, I was able to change gnu c library to 2.7 and things are working fine now.